# How do I send a doclink via LotusScript?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I am iterating through a view of unprocessed requests in LS in a database, and wish to send a reminder with doclink (rather than the doc itself) to the laggards via email.  Do I have to manually assemble a rich text item to make a doclink or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy to create a doclink using Lotusscript.

```
Set body = New NotesRichTextItem(maildoc,"Body")
Call body.AppendDocLink(doc, "Click me")
```

And if you want to send an email, use the class in the link below, it even have built-in support for doclinks. :-)

http://blog.texasswede.com/lotusscript-mail-notification-class/

Answer (score 1):

There is the [NotesNewsletter](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lotusscript/lotusscript.nsf/1efb1287fc7c27388525642e0074f2b6/fc618ad1a057bf228525642e007687dd?OpenDocument) class that can help. Essentially it can create a memo containing doclinks to a collection of documents.